# Specify JDK for Maven to use

Tags: maven-2, settings, java, pom.xml

I am trying to build a Hudson plugin I've modified and it requires jdk1.6. This is fine, but I don't see how I can tell maven where the different jdk is. I've found few mentions on the internet but they don't seem to apply to me. Some suggest adding some config to `.m2/settings.xml` but I don't have a `settings.xml`. Plus, I don't want to use 1.6 for all maven builds.

One kink is I am using `mvn` in cygwin, if that matters at all. It appears I should be able to make the specification in the project pom file, but the existing pom is pretty bare.

So bottom line is, is there a way to specify a jdk for a single invocation of maven?

Comment: IntelliJ-specific answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25888023/how-to-change-java-version-for-maven-in-intellij/59885408#59885408

Answer (score 195, accepted):

> So bottom line is, is there a way to specify a jdk for a single invocation of maven?

Temporarily change the value of your `JAVA_HOME` environment variable.

Comment: Example in windows: `set JAVA_HOME="C:\Java\jdk7"`

Comment: in lubuntu: JAVA_HOME="/home/desa/programas/jdks/jdk1.6.0_45/" mvn -v

Comment: And in case anyone else forgets and spends ages wondering why they can't change it: `JAVA_HOME` can be set for Maven (on Mac at least) in this file: `/private/etc/mavenrc`  - And that can use something like (note the backticks not single quotes!): ``export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7.0_75` ``

Comment: Unix: `export JAVA_HOME='D:/dev/java/jdk8/jre'` (works for me)

Comment: I appreciate @Cerber's answer below, but in the end, this is just simpler and avoids any more subtle errors.  It also mimicks the way CI servers like Jenkins essentially do it.

Comment: if I change JAVA_HOME and then I do `java -version`, it still prints the previous version.

Comment: Based on this answer I run the following before executing maven: 

`export JAVA_HOME=\`java -XshowSettings:properties -version 2>&1 | grep java.home | awk '{ print $3; }'\``

Comment: To change `JAVA_HOME` for a single invocation without having to reset it, use `JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\jdk-13.0.2" mvn --version`

Comment: How to force Maven to run itself using JDK 11 and build project using JDK 1.5 ?

Comment: @ocramot That's because when you run `java -version` your **shell** is looking up the location of the `java` program in your `PATH` environment variable. Maven, on the other hand, is looking up where your JRE is via the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable.

Answer (score 106):

Seems that maven now gives a solution here : [Compiling Sources Using A Different JDK](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/compile-using-different-jdk.html)

Let's say your `JAVA_HOME` points to JDK7 (which will run maven processes)

Your `pom.xml` could be :

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <!-- we want JDK 1.6 source and binary compatiblility -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- ... -->
        <!-- we want sources to be processed by a specific 1.6 javac -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
              <verbose>true</verbose>
              <fork>true</fork>
              <executable>${JAVA_1_6_HOME}/bin/javac</executable>
              <compilerVersion>1.3</compilerVersion>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

If your developpers just add (and customize) the following lines in their `settings.xml`, your pom will be platform independant :

```
<settings>
  [...]
  <profiles>
    [...]
    <profile>
      <id>compiler</id>
        <properties>
          <JAVA_1_4_HOME>C:\Program Files\Java\j2sdk1.4.2_09</JAVA_1_4_HOME>
          <JAVA_1_6_HOME>C:\Program Files\Java\j2sdk1.6.0_18</JAVA_1_6_HOME>
        </properties>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  [...]
  <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>compiler</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

Comment: Voted up! I found I can use `-Dmaven.compiler.fork=true` and `-Dmaven.compiler.executable=/path/to/target/javac` in command line.

Comment: even using those java-opts, you still must add this to the compiler plugin <executable>${maven.compiler.executable}</executable>

Comment: @JinKwon Passing options with -D works fine, even without defining it in the compiler plugin section. This is nice for occasional use or for scripting. You should put it in a separate answer so we can vote it up!

Comment: This solution failed when I try to run tests in Java 8 I was getting *Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 *

Comment: I was hoping to be able to use the same method to generate the JAR file using the `maven-jar-plugin` but it looks like it is not supported. The only method to generate JAR using a specific JDK is by setting `PATH` and `JAVA_HOME`. Any other method you are aware of?

Answer (score 58):

[compile:compile](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html) has [a user property](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#executable) that allows you to specify a path to the `javac`.

Note that this user property only works when `fork` is `true` which is `false` by default.

```
$ mvn -Dmaven.compiler.fork=true -Dmaven.compiler.executable=/path/to/the/javac compile
```

You might have to double quote the value if it contains spaces.

```
> mvn -Dmaven.compiler.fork=true -Dmaven.compiler.executable="C:\...\javac" compile
```

See also [Maven custom properties precedence](https://davidmarquis.wordpress.com/2011/01/13/maven-custom-properties-precedence/).

Comment: I've also needed to overwrite my `JAVA_HOME` variable.
For example (in bash shell):
`JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/ mvn -Dmaven.compiler.fork=true -Dmaven.compiler.executable=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac spring-boot:run`

Answer (score 23):

As u said "Plus, I don't want to use 1.6 for all maven builds."....So better I will say modify your pom file and specify which jdk version to use.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.9</source>
                <target>1.9</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

It will ensure that your particular project uses that version of jdk.

Comment: This is just the starting point, but not the solution. This is the requirement for the maven compiler plugin to compile for 1.7. And then the trick is to make maven really capable of compiling for 1.7, which is not so trivial if your current java version is different...

Comment: That is other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16723533/how-do-you-specify-the-java-compiler-version-in-a-pom-xml-file

Answer (score 18):

I say you setup the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable like Pascal is saying:
In Cygwin if you use bash as your shell should be:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/cygdrive/c/pathtothejdk
```

It never harms to also **prepend** the java `bin` directory path to the `PATH` environment variable with:

```
export PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/bin:${PATH}
```

Also add `maven-enforce-plugin` to make sure the right JDK is used. This is a good practice for your pom.

```
<build>
 <plugins>
   <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>enforce-versions</id>
          <goals>
            <goal>enforce</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <rules>
              <requireJavaVersion>
                <version>1.6</version>
              </requireJavaVersion>
            </rules>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Please, see [Maven Enforcer plugin – Usage](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin/usage.html).

Comment: This was perfect for specifying the *exact* version of the JDK.  For example, I have a project that fails when using the initial JDK 1.8, but if using JDK 1.8.0_77, it works just fine.  I had both JDKs installed, and with this solution maven told me I was using the wrong version of 1.8 until I changed my JAVA_HOME path to target the specific 1.8.0_77 folder.  The other answers did not allow you to be so granular on the version.

Answer (score 18):

If you have installed Java through `brew` in `Mac` then chances are you will find your Java Home Directory here:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home
```

The next step now would be to find which `Java Home` directory maven is pointing to. To find it type in the command: 
`mvn -version`

[image]

The fields we are interested in here is:
`Java version` and `runtime`.

Maven is currently pointing to `Java 13`. Also, you can see the Java Home path under the key runtime, which is:

`/usr/local/Cellar/openjdk/13.0.2+8_2/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home`


To change the Java version of the maven, we need to add the `Java 8` home path to the `JAVA_HOME` env variable.

To do that we need to run the command: 
`export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home`
in the terminal.

Now if we check the maven version, we can see that it is pointing to Java 8 now.

[image]

The problem with this is if you check the maven version again in the new terminal, you will find that it is pointing to the Java 13. To avoid this I would suggest adding the `JAVA_HOME` variable in the `~/.profile` file.

This way whenever your terminal is loading it will take up the value you defined in the JAVA_HOME by default. This is the line you need to add in the `~/.profile` file:

`export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home`

You can open up a new terminal and check the Maven version, (`mvn -version`) and you will find it is pointing to the Java 8 this time.

Comment: I was checking by Bash profile and maven but both have different JAVA Versions. My JAVA_HOME looks: JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_281.jdk/Contents/Home My Maven reads the runtime as –
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_281.jdk/Contents/Home

Comment: One more thing. I tried to change JAVA_HOME, but despite doing so, the command (mvn -version) kept telling me that I had Java 13. What I did was set a wrong path in JAVA_HOME (with and error inside the path), and then the correct one. This caused the Java path to be nulled and then it was refreshed in Maven.

Answer (score 13):

I know its an old thread. But I was having some issues with something similar to this in Maven for Java 8 compiler source. I figured this out with a quick fix mentioned in [this article](http://kanssfer.guru/setting-compiler-source-and-target-for-maven-in-pom-xml/) thought I can put it here and maybe can help others:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

Comment: A Maven Update might be required after adding these lines (Eclipse: Right click on the project, Maven, Update project)

Comment: Setting maven.compiler properties doesn't prevent the code from using methods added in java 11. For instances String.repeat(). This when building with jdk 11. So the maven builds but I wish it would fail

Answer (score 7):

Maven uses variable $JAVACMD as the final java command, set it to where the java executable is will switch maven to different JDK.

Answer (score 7):

You could also set the JDK for Maven in a file in your home directory `~/.mavenrc`:

```
JAVA_HOME='/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.5.jdk/Contents/Home'
```

This environment variable will be checked by the mvn script and used when present:

```
  if [ -f "$HOME/.mavenrc" ] ; then
    . "$HOME/.mavenrc"
  fi
```

https://github.com/CodeFX-org/mvn-java-9/tree/master/mavenrc

Comment: Highly underrated comment, with this I was able to persistently set the JAVA_HOME version in RHEL 8

Comment: Also worked perfectly on MacOS 12.4 with latest and version 11 of openjdk installed through homebrew

Answer (score 3):

Hudson also allows you to define several Java runtimes, and let you invoke Maven with one of these.  Have a closer look on the configuration page.

Comment: The OP is building an hudson plugin on the command line, not under hudson (at least, this is my understanding).

Answer (score 3):

Yet another alternative to manage multiple jdk versions is [jEnv](https://www.jenv.be/)

After installation, you can simply change java version "locally" i.e. for a specific project directory by:

```
jenv local 1.6
```

This will also make mvn use that version locally, when you enable the mvn plugin:

```
jenv enable-plugin maven
```

Comment: Thanks for the jenv maven recommendation.

Answer (score 3):

I update my ~/.m2/settings.xml

```
<settings>
  <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>j8</id>
            <profile>
            <id>j8</id>
            <properties>
                <maven.compiler.fork>true</maven.compiler.fork>
                <maven.compiler.executable>${env.JAVA_HOME8}/bin/javac.exe</maven.compiler.executable>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>j11</id>
            <properties>
                <maven.compiler.fork>true</maven.compiler.fork>
                <maven.compiler.executable>${env.JAVA_HOME11}/bin/javac.exe</maven.compiler.executable>
            </properties>
        </profile>
  </profiles>
<settings>
```

For build with Java8 I run mvn with properties:

```
mvn compile -Pj8
```

and for Java 11

```
mvn compile -Pj11
```

Answer (score 2):

If nothing else works and even after you set JAVA_HOME to a *correct* path, check if there is no override of the JAVA_HOME path in `<user>/.mavenrc`!

As a further tip, the `mvn` file is a bash script (on Linux).. so if necessary you can inspect the source [and change it].

Answer (score 0):

I  had  build  problem  with  maven  within  Eclipse on Windows 7.

Though I  observed  mvn build  was  running  just  fine  from command  line.

```
mvn -T 5 -B -e -X -U -P test clean install -Dmaven.surefire.debug  --settings ..\..\infra-scripts\maven-conf\settings.xml   > output.log
```

Eclipse  was  considering  as  default JVM a  JRE  installation  instead  of JDK  so  it  was  failing  on compilation.

I  added to eclipse.ini  following line:

```
-vm
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin
```

Also  when  starting  from eclipse  I  used in "Goals"  section following list:

```
-T 5 -B -e -X -U -P test clean install -Dmaven.surefire.debug  --settings ..\..\infra-scripts\maven-conf\settings.xml
```

Compilation error  got  solved.

Answer (score 0):

For Java 9 :

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>9</source>
                <target>9</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```