# invalid target release: 1.7

Tags: java, maven, java-7

I have seen similar questions, but haven't yet found the answer.

Using maven compile, I get:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:compile (default-compile) on project api: Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 1.7 -> [Help 1]
```

Here is the pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.7</source>
        <target>1.7</target>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Javac version:

```
javac 1.7.0_25
```

Java version:

```
java version "1.7.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_25-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)
```

Any idea what it could be?

Comment: Most likely maven is running using Java 6.

Comment: I would check all your environment variables to see if any are using Java 6. e.g. Java 7 might be on your path but I remember maven using JAVA_HOME or something like it.

Comment: Execute `mvn -version`. It will tell you which Java it uses.

Comment: you are right, mvn is using java 1.6 - how can I change this?

Comment: set the JAVA_HOME variable to your JDK7 home directory.

Answer (score 159, accepted):

You need to set JAVA_HOME to your jdk7 home directory, for example on Microsoft Windows:

- "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_40"

or on OS X:

- /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home

Comment: On a Mac, where jdk6 and jdk7 are installed, this can be forced in ~/.profile: `export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7)`

Comment: jdk8 can also be used to get jdk7 compliance

Comment: remember to reload ~/.profile on the mac with: `source ~/.profile`

Comment: This probably works for a lot of things but it's not enough for Maven and certainly not for the maven compiler plugin.

Check Mike's answer to his own question here:
[stackoverflow question 24705877](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24705877/cant-get-maven-to-recognize-java-1-8)
This solved the issue for me both command line AND within eclipse.
Also, @LinGao answer to [stackoverflow question 2503658](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503658/specify-jdk-for-maven-to-use) and the use of the  $JAVACMD variable might help.

Answer (score 42):

Other than setting `JAVA_HOME` environment variable, you got to make sure you are using the correct JDK in your Maven run configuration. Go to *Run* -> *Run Configuration*, select your Maven Build configuration, go to JRE tab and set the correct Runtime JRE.

[image: Maven run configuration]

Comment: +1, I knew I was forgetting to update something... The default option (for me) when creating a configuration was the "Alternate JRE". If anyone else runs across this, make sure your maven plugin AND configurations are updated properly!

Comment: I had the right JAVA_HOME for Java 8 but I was still lacking this. You solved my problem, thanks

Answer (score 3):

In IntelliJ IDEA this happened to me when I imported a project that had been working fine and running with Java 1.7. I apparently hadn't notified IntelliJ that java 1.7 had been installed on my machine, and it wasn't finding my `$JAVA_HOME`.

On a Mac, this is resolved by:

Right clicking on the module | Module Settings | Project

and adding the 1.7 SDK by selecting "New" in the Project SDK.

Then go to the main IntelliJ IDEA menu | Preferences | Maven | Runner

and select the correct JRE. In my case it updated correctly Use Project SDK, which was now 1.7.

Comment: Note that there are Project Settings and Preferences for Intellij on a Mac at least, I had to go to Settings -> Build Exec, Deploy -> Java Compiler and then set the project bytecode version as needed.

Answer (score 1):

When maven is working outside of Eclipse, but giving this error after a JDK change, Go to your Maven Run Configuration, and at the bottom of the Main page, there's a 'Maven Runtime' option.  Mine was using the Embedded Maven, so after switching it to use my external maven, it worked.

Comment: where is the Maven Run Configuration, please?

Comment: Right click on your build.xml, go to 'Run as' and then 'Run Configuration' should be the last option.  If you scroll through the types of run configs, one is 'Maven Build', and that has an option to choose the 'Maven Runtime'.  There's a 'configure' button next to that

Answer (score 0):

This probably works for a lot of things but it's not enough for Maven and certainly not for the maven compiler plugin.

Check Mike's answer to his own question here:
[stackoverflow question 24705877](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24705877/cant-get-maven-to-recognize-java-1-8)

This solved the issue for me both command line AND within eclipse.

Also, @LinGao answer to [stackoverflow question 2503658](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503658/specify-jdk-for-maven-to-use) and the use of the  $JAVACMD variable might help but I haven't tested it myself.