# Transform application compiled in jdk1.4 to jdk1.7

Tags: java, ant, upgrade, jdk1.4

I'm working on an application that has been created long time ago (maybe 2008/2009). Now I got the task of upgrading the server.
Previously it was compiled in jdk1.4. Now I have to make the application compatible with jdk1.7. I tried to compile it with jre7 and I've changed source and target value of ant build.xml file to `1.7`. And also in ANT build the jre7 is selected as compiler environment.
I'm getting the following error message:

```
 [javac] javac: invalid target release: 1.7
    [javac] Usage: javac <options> <source files>
    [javac] where possible options include:
    [javac]   -g                        Generate all debugging info
    [javac]   -g:none                   Generate no debugging info
    [javac]   -g:{lines,vars,source}    Generate only some debugging info
    [javac]   -nowarn                   Generate no warnings
    [javac]   -verbose                  Output messages about what the compiler is doing
    [javac]   -deprecation              Output source locations where deprecated APIs are used
    [javac]   -classpath <path>         Specify where to find user class files
    [javac]   -sourcepath <path>        Specify where to find input source files
    [javac]   -bootclasspath <path>     Override location of bootstrap class files
    [javac]   -extdirs <dirs>           Override location of installed extensions
    [javac]   -d <directory>            Specify where to place generated class files
    [javac]   -encoding <encoding>      Specify character encoding used by source files
    [javac]   -source <release>         Provide source compatibility with specified release
    [javac]   -target <release>         Generate class files for specific VM version
    [javac]   -help                     Print a synopsis of standard options
```

I tried to print the java version using following line:

and it shows :

> [echo] Using Java version 1.7.

What (other) changes do I need to make to make it work with jdk1.7?

Comment: Check in your ant xml and see if there is any 'target' parameter set to 1.4

Comment: possible duplicate of [invalid target release: 1.7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19891423/invalid-target-release-1-7)

Comment: Java 1.4 was 2002, Java 5 came out in 2004 and Java 6 came out in 2006.

Comment: @RatshiḓahoWayne in my build.xml target parameter is as follows: <property name="ant.build.javac.source" value="1.7"/>
  <property name="ant.build.javac.target" value="1.7"/> 
  <property name="ant.build.javac.encoding" value="ISO-8859-15"/>

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Ya may be you're right about the released year. But I was telling about the application I'm working. However this apps was created in 2008 but it was using jdk1.4 in a OAS application server.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose Thanks for the information. May be it's releated to the thread you indicated but I didn't found solution there. because in my case I'v setted the JAVA_HOME to the jdk1.7 same as in the eclipse project properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved.
I was trying to compile with JRE7 instead of jdk1.7.
with jdk1.7 installed and target and source changed in ant build.xml file solved my problem.