# error compiling java7 project with maven (heroku)

Tags: java, git, maven, heroku

I'm trying to upload on heroku simple servlet with maven. Locally my servlet is working just fine but when i use:

`git push heroku master`

I get "BUILD FAILURE" with error message:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:
3.1:compile (default-compile) on project HelloServlet: Fatal error compiling: 
invalid target release: 1.7 -> [Help 1]
```

I changed everything to Java 1.7 in system variables, maven is running Java 1.7, javac version is 1.7?

Am I missing something here?

edit: my JAVA_HOME and error screenshot

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you set the JAVA_HOME environment variable? If you have what does mvn -version show?. Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19891423/invalid-target-release-1-7

Comment: i have setted it all, mvn -version shows D:\workspace-STS\DrinkApp>mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.2.3 (33f8c3e1027c3ddde99d3cdebad2656a31e8fdf4; 2014-08-11T22:58:1
0+02:00)
Maven home: C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.2.3
Java version: 1.7.0_71, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 8.1", version: "6.3", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default heroku apps run on OpenJDK 6.You have to add additional properties to make your app use Open JDK 7 on heroku.

Refer : https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/add-java-version-to-an-existing-maven-app

Answer (score 1):

Did you set `source` and `target` configuration parameters of `maven-compiler-plugin` correctly?

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html

In your `pom.xml`:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.7</source>
        <target>1.7</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: yes my pom.xml was fine but heroku runs on default OpenJDK6 so that was problem. Thanks for help!