# Error in heroku build: invalid target release

Tags: spring-boot, heroku

When i insert the command **git push heroku master** in order to deploy in eroku the following error appear

```
fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 15 -> [Help 1]
```

Following is my pom.xml

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.wk</groupId>
    <artifactId>manager</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>manager</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>15</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <type>maven-plugin</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I looked for similar question but dont solve my problem
i even added in my properties:

```
java.runtime.version=15
```

but didnt work

changed the maven home for jdk 15 still not work

I am following the steps of this  tutorial https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/candidate-manager-api/deploy/heroku-git

how can i solve this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53604111/heroku-cannot-deploy-java-11-spring-boot-app) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60012401/invalid-target-release-12-when-pushing-the-heroku-repo) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26573044/error-compiling-java7-project-with-maven-heroku) which are related to this question,

you should create a file called `system.properties` in the root of your project, and put:

```
java.runtime.version=15
```

Comment: I see now https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-support. Thanks