# Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 1.8 -> [Help 1]

Tags: java, maven

Similar problem like one posted on [invalid target release: 1.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19891423/invalid-target-release-1-7) but after following the blog my problem is still unresolved.

> Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project hm_app: Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 1.8 -> [Help 1]

I was following [as tutorial](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html) when I faced this problem.

```
abt java & mvn

C:\mvn>echo %JAVA_HOME% 
C:\mvn>echo %JRE_HOME%
C:\mvn>echo %MAVEN_HOME% yields
```

outputs

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51
C:\Program Files\Java\jre7
C:\apache-maven-3.0.4
```

Comment: ...and you're sure you have Java 8 installed somewhere?

Comment: i have x86 , 64 java 7 and no java 8

Comment: Okay.  So why are you trying to compile Java 8 code without a Java 8 compiler?

Comment: @Makoto ty for looking into my problem installing java 8 solved it ....  ty man :)

Comment: @Makoto Finally i got what u were saying "Okay. So why are you trying to compile Java 8 code without a Java 8 compiler?"  so i just changed in my pom.xml file java.version>1.8</java.version> to java.version>1.7</java.version> and i could use mvn compile on java7 too

Answer (score 318, accepted):

You have set your `%JAVA_HOME` to jdk 1.7, but you are trying to compile using 1.8. Install jdk 1.8 and make sure your `%JAVA_HOME` points to that or drop the target release to 1.7.

> invalid target release: 1.8

The target release refers to the jdk version.

Comment: one more possible solution in my case is edit pom.xml file java.version>1.8</java.version> to java.version>1.7</java.version>

Comment: That is specifically where maven looks for the java version. So effectively you changed the java version to one you had installed on your %JAVA_HOME.

Comment: On a my mac, I do export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8` to set the JAVA_HOME to the proper location for 1.8 JDK.  Supply your favorite version in place of 1.8.  (There are backticks after = and after 8).

Comment: Yes, right u got me. I changed it to compile another legacy program which only supports 1.7 yesterday :D Thanks!

Answer (score 44):

Put the value in the plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The error was use:

```
<source>${java.version}</source>
<target>${java.version}</target>
```

Comment: In my case, the solution is to set both source and target to 1.7

Comment: in what file can I find this?

Comment: @YusrilMaulidanRaji pom.xml

Answer (score 25):

In my case the maven "Run configuration" was using the wrong JRE (1.7). Be sure to check **Run -> Run Configurations -> (Tab) JRE** to be some jdk1.8.x.

Comment: that is true, so we have following things to check next time if this error comes: JAVA_HOME, BUILD_Configuration, RUN_Configuration

Answer (score 17):

The issue was resolved as I was having a JDK pointing to 1.7 and JRE pointing to 1.8. Check in the command prompt by typing

```
java -version
```

and

```
javac -version
```

Both should be same.

Answer (score 6):

For eclipse here is how I solved my problem:

1. Preferences --> Compiler --> Compiler Complainer Level (Change to 1.8)
   [image]
2. Perferences --> Installed JREs --> select JAVA SE 8 1.8
   [image]
3. Rebuild via maven using Run as maven build.

It shouldn't show you the invalid target error anymore. 
Note: I didn't have to set or change any other variables in my terminal.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

Putting that in your .profile will dynamically take care of your `$JAVA_HOME`

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
```

Close your shell afterwards, open a new one and test with

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

It should display something like

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home
```

**If not**, remove any other assignments of JAVA_HOME in your startup scripts. Remember, that these startup scripts start with a `.` so they are hidden and won't be included when using `*` wildcard, e.g. if you want to grep all files of your home directory, you need to:

```
grep -s JAVA_HOME ~/.* --exclude=.bash_history
```

Answer (score 4):

I faced this issue deploying on Dokku, for some reason it was choosing JDK 1.7

Creating a `system.properties` file and setting `java.runtime.version=1.8` solved the issue. Dokku now uses Java version 8.
[Choosing a JDK on Heroku](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-java)

I Never had to do it before...

Comment: The hint still works. I had to search a lot to change the Java version in Dokku to 11. Thank you very much.

Comment: You made my day ! Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by Camila Macedo - you have to explicitly point the java version for compiler-plugin. For spring boot you can do that by next property:

```
  <properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <maven.compiler.release>8</maven.compiler.release>
  </properties>
```

Comment: Yes, setting `maven.compiler.release` fixed it in my Maven project.

Answer (score 3):

I have similar problem when I was trying to deploy my spring boot project to heroku, although my problem is `invalid target release: 11`.
I solved it by adding a new file `system.properties` and the content added to the file is `java.runtime.version=11` (For me I am using JDK 11).

Answer (score 2):

Using IntelliJ I just had to install another (higher) JDK Version. After restarting IDE, everything worked and even all dependencies were solved.

Comment: Restarting intelliJ was the key for me. I updated the environment variable of JAVA_HOME to point to different java version, but it appears the system variable doesn't refresh in existing CMD session. Possibly it would be enough to just create new Terminal session.

Answer (score 1):

The problem I was facing was that I was able to make a maven build from the command prompt but not from Eclipse.What worked for me in eclipse is that I changed the run configuration to point to JRE folder inside of JDK rather than leaving it in JDK folder only as per the standard.This solution may work for you as well but try this if and only if all the java paths are correct, java and javac are showing the same version as present in the target of pom.xml.

Comment: This was my problem and solution.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows machine you can temporarily set Java version.
For example, to change the version to Java 8, run this command on `cmd`:

```
set JAVA_HOME=C:\\...\jdk1.8.0_65
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case (IntelliJ), I needed to check if I had **the right Runner** for maven:

1. Preferences
2. Build, Execution, Deployment
3. Maven -> Runner

[image: Preferences]

Answer (score 0):

This question wasn't asking explicitly about Docker, but I received the same error when I had a pom.xml file that was targeting 1.9...

```
<properties>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  <maven.compiler.source>1.9</maven.compiler.source>
  <maven.compiler.target>1.9</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

... but then tried to run tests against a Docker container by specifying "maven" by itself.

```
docker run -t --rm -v m2_repository:/root/.m2/repository -v $(pwd):/work -w /work maven mvn -e test
```

For me, the fix was to target the exact version I needed.

```
docker run -t --rm -v m2_repository:/root/.m2/repository -v $(pwd):/work -w /work maven:3.5.2-jdk-9 mvn test
```

*(You can [learn more here](https://hub.docker.com/_/maven/).)*

Answer (score 0):

Do a force Maven Update which will bring the compatible 1.8 Jar Versions and then while building, update the JRE Versions in Execute environment to 1.8 from Run Configurations and hit RUN

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Eclipse IDE then go inside Window menu and select preferences and there you search for installed JREs and select the JRE you need to build the project

Answer (score 0):

NETBEANS
**Error**:
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.pluginsmaven-compiler-plugin3.1compile (default-compile) on project doit Fatal error compiling invalid target release 11 - [Help 1]

**How I solved my problem:**
.Right click on the project.
.Go to Properties.
.Click on Source.
.Go to Source/Binary Format and change to the latest version

In my case (1.8)

Answer (score 0):

First, if you are using eclipse, please check Build Path -> Configure Build Path -> Java Build Path, see which java version your project is using. I recommend using Java 1.8.
Second, check the pom.xml file. ctrl + F to search the text "java.version" => change it to 1.8.
Third install Java 1.8 and then change your JAVE_HOME path to point to Java 1.8 folder.

Answer (score 0):

Verify your jdk version in your pom.xml and environmental variables are same or not. if not make it same.

At pom.xml ->

```
<properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
</properties>
```

At environmental variables ->
JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.13

Answer (score 0):

In my case bumping the version of the `maven-compiler-plugin` from `3.8.1` to `3.10.1` solved the issue:

```
<plugin>
   <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>3.10.1</version>
   <configuration>
   <release>${maven.compiler.release}</release>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

where `${maven.compiler.release}` = your java version

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar failure when I tried to build a Maven project in Netbeans.
My pom file looks like this:

```
<properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <exec.mainClass>com.example.Main</exec.mainClass>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
            <configuration>
            <source>17</source>
            <target>17</target>
                <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin> 
        ...
```

But Java platform for the project was set to 1.8 (as it is the default Java platform in my Netbeans configuration).

Solution: `Right-click on project Properties->Build->Compile->Java Platform-> choose JDK 17 from dropdown.`

If the dropdown does not have the required Java platform, it should be downloaded, installed, and then configured thru `Tools->Java platforms`.

Answer (score -4):

What worked in my case is this:

I opened the `pom.xml` and replaced the one of the plug-ins as below.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.7</source>
        <target>1.7</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Before I edited the source and target tags both had `1.8`, I changed that to `1.7` and it worked.

Comment: Do you understand the change that you have done or did you just make the change hoping for the best?

Comment: Both. I understand that the project is now running on Java 1.7 version. I  did that hoping it will work.