# Failing Maven build

Tags: java, maven, tfs, tfsbuild

I'm running a build in TFS 2015 and I get this error:

[ERROR]

l org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.6.2:compile (default-compile) on project pia-branch-rest-api: Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 1.8 -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.6.2:compile (default-compile) on project pia-branch-rest-api: Fatal error compiling

at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)

Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Fatal error compiling

222 
2018-07-25T11:22:37.0150577Z    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:963)

223 
2018-07-25T11:22:37.0150577Z    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:158)

224 
2018-07-25T11:22:37.0150577Z    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)

225 
2018-07-25T11:22:37.0150577Z    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)

226 
2018-07-25T11:22:37.0150577Z    ... 19 more

227 
2018-07-25T11:22:37.0306811Z Caused by: org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.CompilerException: invalid target release: 1.8

228 
2018-07-25T11:22:37.0306811Z    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavaxToolsCompiler.compileInProcess(JavaxToolsCompiler.java:173)

229 
2018-07-25T11:22:37.0306811Z    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler.performCompile(JavacCompiler.java:174)

230 
2018-07-25T11:22:37.0306811Z    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:952)

231 
2018-07-25T11:22:37.0306811Z    ... 22 more

232 
2018-07-25T11:22:37.0306811Z Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid target release: 1.8

233 
2018-07-25T11:22:37.0306811Z    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.RecognizedOptions$GrumpyHelper.error(RecognizedOptions.java:75)

234 
2018-07-25T11:22:37.0306811Z    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.RecognizedOptions$14.process(RecognizedOptions.java:380)

235 
2018-07-25T11:22:37.0306811Z    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTool.processOptions(JavacTool.java:247)

at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTool.getTask(JavacTool.java:207)

at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTool.getTask(JavacTool.java:53)

at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavaxToolsCompiler.compileInProcess(JavaxToolsCompiler.java:125)

Pom.xml ( snippet)

```
 <build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.plugin.compiler.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${compile.source.version}</source>
                    <target>${compile.target.version}</target>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.plugin.deploy.version}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.plugin.jar.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addDefaultSpecificationEntries>true</addDefaultSpecificationEntries>
                            <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                        </manifest>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Vendor-Url>${project.organization.url}</Vendor-Url>
                            <Build-Revision>${buildNumber}</Build-Revision>
                            <Build-Date>${timestamp}</Build-Date>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                    <skipIfEmpty>true</skipIfEmpty>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test-jar</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.plugin.javadoc.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnError>false</failOnError>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.plugin.release.version}</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.google.code.maven-scm-provider-svnjava</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-scm-provider-svnjava</artifactId>
                        <version>${maven.scm.provider.svnjava.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <configuration>
                    <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
                    <providerImplementations>
                        <svn>javasvn</svn>
                    </providerImplementations>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.plugin.resources.version}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.plugin.source.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addDefaultSpecificationEntries>true</addDefaultSpecificationEntries>
                            <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                        </manifest>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Vendor-Url>${project.organization.url}</Vendor-Url>
                            <Build-Revision>${buildNumber}</Build-Revision>
                            <Build-Date>${timestamp}</Build-Date>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-sources</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-test-sources</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.plugin.surefire.version}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.plugin.buildnumber.version}</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.google.code.maven-scm-provider-svnjava</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-scm-provider-svnjava</artifactId>
                        <version>${maven.scm.provider.svnjava.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.tmatesoft.svnkit</groupId>
                        <artifactId>svnkit</artifactId>
                        <version>${svnkit.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- never touch svn -->
                    <doCheck>false</doCheck>
                    <doUpdate>false</doUpdate>
                    <timestampFormat>{0,date,yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}</timestampFormat>
                    <providerImplementations>
                        <svn>javasvn</svn>
                    </providerImplementations>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>


</build>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>buildnumber-plugin</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <!-- This profile is activated if NO system property 'skipBuildnumber'
                    is found. Disable this profile by specifying -DskipBuildnumber=true on the
                    commandline -->
                <name>!skipBuildnumber</name>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <build>
             <plugins>
             <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
        <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>buildnumber</id>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
            <goal>create</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
            <format>{0,number}</format>
            <items>
            <item>buildNumber</item>
            </items>                    
            <doCheck>false</doCheck>
            <doUpdate>false</doUpdate>
            <revisionOnScmFailure>unknownbuild</revisionOnScmFailure>   
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

Comment: Please provide at least excerpts from your pom.xml.

Comment: Also, please include all the relevant parts of the console output _as text_ into the question. It's very cumbersome to work with images of text.

Comment: it works thanks to andy LiMSFT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the **Capabilities** of your build agent.

Make sure you have installed the **SDK 1.8**, and `JAVA_HOME` is set to that version,  and it's **identified** by the build agent.

Run below commands on the build agent machine to check the JAVA_HOME settings:

```
echo %JAVA_HOME% 
echo %JDK_HOME%
echo %JRE_HOME%
```

More information please refer to this thread for troubleshooting: [Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 1.8 -> [Help 1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28291691/fatal-error-compiling-invalid-target-release-1-8-help-1?rq=1)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Could you please check if your JAVA_HOME is set to SDK of 1.8