# I've been trying to figure out how to correct this error and i can't seem to be getting anywhere

Tags: java

I tried doing this login form but it keeps on giving me the same error. Where did I do wrong?

```java
public class Login extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    public Login() {
        initComponents();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(625, 450));
        setResizable(false);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 511, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 337, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 50)); 
        jLabel1.setText("LOGIN");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(55, 55, 55)
                        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(214, 214, 214)
                        .addComponent(jLabel1)))
                .addContainerGap(57, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(21, 21, 21)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        


    public static void main(String args[]) {

        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            new Login().setVisible(true);
        });
    }


    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;

}
```

I expected a preview of my login form but instead I got this

```
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 1.766 s
Finished at: 2019-10-29T21:40:45-05:00
Final Memory: 8M/34M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project Login_System: Fatal error compiling: error: invalid target release: 13 -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 1.8 -> \[Help 1\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28291691/fatal-error-compiling-invalid-target-release-1-8-help-1)

Answer (score 1):

The following error message has shown you the reason actually:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project Login_System: Fatal error compiling: error: invalid target release: 13 -> [Help 1]
```

Your current maven compiler plugin with version 3.1 is not able to compile for Java 13.

You should use a newer maven-compiler-plugin, and also check which java version it is running on by:

On Unix/Linux:

```
mvn --version | grep -i java
```