# Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 12 -> [Help 1]

Tags: java, mysql, maven, maven-plugin, codeanywhere

[image]

I am using Codeanywhere and I need to run a web server with maven. But it gives me this error: Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 12 -> [Help 1], as also seen in the image but I don't understand how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Maven is trying to compile using Java 12, but it cannot be found. Either set the path correctly to your JDK 12 or set the target JDK in pom.xml to something else (the easiest way is to set the `maven.compiler.target` property). [See similar answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28291691/fatal-error-compiling-invalid-target-release-1-8-help-1)

Comment: so i have to change <maven.compiler.target> 12 </maven.compiler.target>?
i don't know how to change it.
I used netbeans to write the code and the default version used is JDK 12 so I don't know what to change and how to put the path

Comment: No, change it to a version that is actually installed on your system. Try opening a command line and type `java -version`. Note that 12 is an outdated non-LTS version that is not supported by most JDK vendors.

Comment: Happy to hear! You also may accept the answer if it did answer your question.