# Maven cannot compile Google Cloud Dataflow SDK

Tags: maven, google-cloud-dataflow

I cannot compile the Google Cloud Dataflow SDK. I am getting an error when I do "mvn install":

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all: Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 1.7 -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all: Fatal error compiling
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:355)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:216)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:160)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Fatal error compiling
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:796)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:129)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.CompilerException: invalid target release: 1.7
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavaxToolsCompiler.compileInProcess(JavaxToolsCompiler.java:191)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler.performCompile(JavacCompiler.java:169)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:785)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid target release: 1.7
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.RecognizedOptions$GrumpyHelper.error(RecognizedOptions.java:75)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.RecognizedOptions$14.process(RecognizedOptions.java:380)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTool.processOptions(JavacTool.java:247)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTool.getTask(JavacTool.java:207)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTool.getTask(JavacTool.java:53)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavaxToolsCompiler.compileInProcess(JavaxToolsCompiler.java:115)
    ... 24 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is most likely caused by Maven beeing configured to work with a lower Java version than what has been configured to compile the source to.

When running `mvn -v` to get the version information displayed i expect you will see Maven is configured to work with a Java (JDK) version lower than 1.7.

As faar as i know changing the system variable `JAVA_HOME` to point to a Java 1.7 JDK should fix the issue (assumed you are working with a Windows based environment...).

Note: `JAVA_HOME` might be interpreted/ used by other programms/ tools as well

Comment: Thank you. I found the solution on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19891423/invalid-target-release-1-7