# How to make Maven use JDK1.8 instead of JDK1.6

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am new to maven, and I find that though I change the facet of the jdk of the project to 1.8, every time I "update maven",it will get back to jdk 1.6.

Why is that?

I installed jdk 1.8 in my windows, and I am using eclipse.

I read [Specify JDK for Maven to use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503658/specify-jdk-for-maven-to-use) and add the following but it does not work.

```
   <plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>enforce-versions</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>enforce</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <rules>
          <requireJavaVersion>
            <version>1.8</version>
          </requireJavaVersion>
        </rules>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The version of the JDK that maven will use is set in the `maven-compiler-plugin` like so:

```
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.8</source>   <!-- use java 8 -->
      <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

See [`Setting the -source and -target of the Java Compiler`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html) for more information.

Comment: So what about maven-enforcer-plugin, what is this to do and why it solves the thread Specify JDK for Maven to use

Comment: And I tried, one warnning: Overriding managed version 3.1 for maven-compiler-plugin, why there is a warning for the versions.

Comment: i will try this with wildfly :) thk :)

Answer (score 0):

Check the maven compiler plugin to specify source and target java version,

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html

Regards,
Prasanna

Answer (score 0):

maybe too late, but it works for me:

```
<!-- we want JDK 1.8 source and binary compatiblility -->
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <!-- ... -->
    <!-- we want sources to be processed by a specific 1.8 javac -->
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <verbose>true</verbose>
          <fork>true</fork>
          <executable>${JAVA_1_8_HOME}/bin/javac</executable>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Your question help me a lot anyway :) Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

In a comment you asked:

> So what about maven-enforcer-plugin, what is this to do?

According to that [documentation](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin/usage.html) for the plugin:

> *"This goal is meant to be bound to a lifecycle phase and configured in your pom.xml. The enforcers execute the configured rules to check for certain constraints."*

In other words, it checks that certain constraints *have been satisfied*.  It does not *cause* them to be satisfied.

In your example, the effect of the plugin *should be* to cause the build to fail if the Java version is not Java 1.8.

> ... and why it solves the thread "Specify JDK for Maven to use"?

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2505360/139985) you are referring to says this:

> *"And it never harms to ... add maven-enforce-plugin to make sure the right jdk is used. This is a good practice for your pom."*

As you can see, it does not state that maven-enforce-plugin "solves" the problem.  It is actually providing a way to ensure that the problem has been solved ... and fail the build if it hasn't.