# Compiling gwt with maven - specify jvm

Tags: java, maven, gwt

I am trying to specify, in my maven settings.xml and my pom.xml, which jvm to use for my gwt project.

I am using the suggestion from https://stackoverflow.com/a/20787334/265119. I have used this on other, non-gwt projects successfully.

Now however it seems that maven is ignoring this, and continues to use java 8, whereas I have set the following in my settings.xml:

```
<profiles>        
<profile>
<id>default</id>
    <properties>
            <JAVA_1_7_HOME>/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/javac</JAVA_1_7_HOME>
            <JAVA_1_8_HOME>/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/javac</JAVA_1_8_HOME>
        </properties>
</profile>
  </profiles>
  <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>default</activeProfile>
</activeProfiles>
```

And in my pom.xml:

```
 <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>${java.version}</source>
                        <target>${java.version}</target>
                        <executable>${JAVA_1_7_HOME}</executable>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
```

Does anyone know why maven is ignoring these?
Does the gwt maven plugin also need to specify the jvm version?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is the profile *really* activated? Your POM ought to work, but only if the profile is activated.

You can run `mvn help:active-profiles` to find out if your profile is active.

Also, in order for `<executable>` to work, you need to set `<fork>true</fork>` as well. As explained here: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#executable

Comment: Hi @Daniel, yes the profile is active. And I tried adding `<fork>true</fork>` but it did not solve the problem. Thanks

Comment: Is your compiler plugin specified in the `<pluginManagement>` section?

Comment: Hi @Daniel, no, however, I think I am a step closer. The gwt-maven-plugin has a configuration setting for jvm. When I set this I can see it is now using 1.7. Unfortunately this causes a new error - ' javac: invalid flag: -Xmx512m'. The strange thing is this arg doesnt exist in my pom.

Comment: I think it may be the default. Check out the `<extraJvmArgs>` here: https://gwt-maven.googlecode.com/svn/docs/maven-googlewebtoolkit2-plugin/examples.html

Comment: Thank you @Daniel, yes I think you are correct. Thanks. Any idea on how to get around the 'javac: invalid flag: -Xmx512m' error? Would you advice on opening a bug report with Larry Page and Sergey Brin ?

Comment: Try to blank out the field (`<extraJvmArgs />`) or perhaps setting the flag to something innocuous that works for both the JVM and `javac`, like `-verbose`.