# maven, APT problems, eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have a maven project that I am trying to build in my `workspace` in `eclipse`. Now, I changed my `java` path from `'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79'` to `'C:\new\Java\jdk1.7.0_79'` for some valid reasons.

I updated the path in `environment variable` and `eclipse` accordingly. However, when I build the project, I face the following error:

> Project UPF-Desktop is missing required annotation processor
>   library:'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\lib\tools.jar'      Annotation
>   processor factory path     APT Build Problem

`tools.jar` is present in the new `Java` location, but it is looking for `tools.jar` in a non-existing location, altogether.

Comment: does tools.jar exist?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20787334/1746118 this shall help

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you mast update JAVA_HOME path? Is also in advanced system settings