# How to get the Java Runtime environment for Maven Plugin

Tags: java, maven, runtime

I am trying to write a Maven Plugin.  This plugin needs to run a separate java process for a separate jar.  How to obtain the maven java runtime?

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503658/specify-jdk-for-maven-to-use) it may help.

Comment: What kind of problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Right now my solution is to use URLClassLoader in my own maven plugin to load jar files and run the main via reflection.  The obvious issue is the memory constraint.  I am wondering if it is possible to fork a separate process by launching the Java process that launches maven.