# How to fix java language level error in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans-7

How can I fix these java language level error which shows:

> use -source 7 or higher to enable strings in switch

I am using netbeans as an IDE.

Comment: Hello there.. Welcome to Stack Overflow. I think you should take some time to read on [How to ask a good question around here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and take some time to improve this question.. :)

Comment: Look at the JDK currently used by Netbeans and you might need an update. Or else can you post more on the error?

Comment: Are you using maven? If so use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18420462/1540468). Which will work as long as a jdk 7 is installed.

Comment: If you are not using Maven, you can manually set the source Java version in Project Properties > Sources > Source/Binary Format dropdown.   But as Paul says, the use Maven .pom if you are in a Maven project!

Answer (score 1):

With right mouse click on a project name open pop-up menu and choose "Properties". There will be project properties window opened. Choose category "Sources" and change field "Source/Binary Format":

[image: Netbeans Project Properties]

If you have several JVM versions installed, choose the necessary version under "Build/Compile":

[image]