# Settings.xml not picking up my java8 profile from command line

Tags: java, maven, java-8

I have a scenario where I need to run maven from a batch file to use JDK 8,I can't change the pom.xml
 nor can I change the environment variable.But I can change settings.xml.I get the following error as below:

```
[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?
```

I have setup profile as follows:

```
 <profile>
     <id>java8</id>
     <activation>
       <jdk>1.8</jdk>
     </activation>
   <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>   
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>    
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
   </profile>
```

I have activated the profile using below line

```
<activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>java8</activeProfile>
</activeProfiles>
```

But still I get the error No compiler is provided? How do I set the path variable to my Java Home.

Comment: That has nothing to do with the POM, but with the Java on the PATH. Maven picks up the Java from your PATH and sees that it is a JRE, but it needs a JDK.

Comment: java version "1.8.0_202-ea"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-ea-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.202-b03, mixed mode)

Comment: How to make it pick up my JDK without modifying the path in environment variables nor pom.xml

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36647171/927493

Comment: JAVA_HOME is the one which is needed to be changed...

Comment: Use a toolchain otherwise: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-using-toolchains.html You are the free from running Maven with any JDK and compiling your code with JDK8 (or other)