# How do you know the version of Java for a give repository?

Tags: spring-repositories

When I'm going to compile a repository it seems I must guess which version of Java is intended. For example, if I want to compile elasticsearch I read the readme and execute `./gradlew assemble`. Eventually the build fails because I have Java8 and it requires Java11. It is a simple change, but is there a way for me to ask gradle (or maven, when applicable) for the version of Java before I start to compile?

How does developer tools deal with this? They can't possibly just try random versions of JDK until something works. Is it always manual?

Comment: You could always look into the gradle file and check if it specifies a language version. That would be a good indicator. Aside from that, no, there is no automated way to deal with this.

Answer (score 0):

You generally look at source and target for maven-compiler-plugin in Maven so you should be able to look at that:

[Specify JDK for Maven to use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503658/specify-jdk-for-maven-to-use).

And as stated, JDK is backwards-compatible so you can compile with the latest JDK. Maven uses the JAVA_HOME variable by the way.

Comment: OP specifically asked about gradle, not maven, but the gist of this still applies