# force maven to use different java version

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube, maven-toolchains-plugin

I have my existing project that uses Java 1.8
My JAVA_HOME is set to Java 1.8
As a result maven is using Java 1.8 , which is fine
Now our project has decided to start using SonarQube 9.x which runs on Java 11
In addition to run any scan / analysis of our code - it needs Java 11 as well

So here is what I need to be doing :

#1 Compile code using default jdk ( 1.8 ) ( mvn clean install )

#2 Run sonar scan using jdk 11 ( mvn sonar:sonar )

To execute #2 need maven to use jdk 11 while to execute #1 need maven to use jdk 1.8.

After reading various questions on SO came across 'toolchain'

So added toolchains.xml into my 'm2' folder :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<toolchains>
 <!-- JDK toolchains -->
 <toolchain>
  <type>jdk</type>
  <provides>
   <version>1.11</version>
   <vendor>sun</vendor>
  </provides>
  <configuration>
   <jdkHome>C:\construction\tools\jdk-11.0.12</jdkHome>
  </configuration>
</toolchain>
<toolchain>
 <type>jdk</type>
 <provides>
  <version>1.8</version>
  <vendor>sun</vendor>
 </provides>
 <configuration>
  <jdkHome>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191</jdkHome>
 </configuration>
</toolchain>
```

Added toolchain plugin in my projects pom.xml

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-toolchains-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>toolchain</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <toolchains>
                    <jdk>
                        <version>1.11</version>
                        <vendor>sun</vendor>
                    </jdk>
                </toolchains>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Now when I run maven clean install can see in logs that java 11 'seems' to be used :

> [INFO] --- maven-toolchains-plugin:1.1:toolchain (default) @ TreeSurveyAPI ---

> [INFO] Required toolchain: jdk [ vendor='sun' version='1.11' ]
> [INFO] Found matching toolchain for type jdk: JDK[C:\construction\tools\jdk-11.0.12]

> [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) @ TreeSurveyAPI ---
> [INFO] Toolchain in maven-compiler-plugin: JDK[C:\construction\tools\jdk-11.0.12]
> [INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
> [INFO] Compiling 11 source files to C:\construction\xxx\XYZ-main\target\classes

So it 'seems' that maven along with toolchain is using Java 11 to compile the code .
However after executing javap against compiled class file indicates Major version as 52 ( Java 8 )

```
javap -verbose Abc.class | findstr "major"
```

So here are my questions :

#1
in the above case since toolchain points to java 11 shouldnt the code be compiled with java 11 ? why is it using java 8 ?

#2
How can I conditionally use java 8 Vs java 11 ( compile and build using java 8 and run sonar task using java 11 ) ?

Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to configure Java 8 just for the maven compile plugin? Then the build could run on Java 11 in both cases.

Comment: Use JDK11 for build and define `--release` or via `maven.compiler.release` the target for the class files...that works perfectly fine...is easier etc. I would even think to go to build with JDK17 instead of JDK11...

Comment: This is exactly the situation we have to deal with in our enterprise, and from my initial research, I believe (without testing yet) that the previous comment illustrates the basic strategy that should likely work. Note that you can also set the "release" property in the configuration of "maven-compiler-plugin", instead of setting the "target" and "source".

Comment: Are you running mvn clean install from your IDE or from the terminal?

Comment: from the command prompt

Answer (score 0):

You can run your project on java 11 also.
It will run java 8 code no problem for 99% of the cases.
This is what I would do. Therefore, upgrading the projects java version seems to be the easiest solution.

If this does not work, check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20787334/2599899)

Also, if you need to be able to quickly change JVM versions for various tasks and in various folders, you can use this [tool](https://reflectoring.io/manage-jdks-with-jenv/)

Comment: thanks for the response but we are in a micoroservices world with 120+ api so running on java 11 will involve extensive regression which we do not want to do . Unfortunately in our environment introduction of  this tool / new tool will be a challenge and it also seems to need additional work to get it to work on windows . I thought toolchain should help in changing jdk to be used ...

Comment: Got it. Then check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/20787334/2599899

Comment: Which regressions? Is the written code so heavily JDK specific or uses internals?

Comment: thanks @ArthurKlezovich , however the answer in the so link is referring to change JAVA_HOME , now that would imply ( in my case ) to use default JAVA_HOME ( jdk1.8) to compile and build war / jar / ear which is fine , however in the next step I need to run sonar scan so need to change JAVA_HOME to JDK11 , I cannot do this manually and when I had tried to do this via command prompt ( with administrator priveleges ) it still would refuse to change to jdk11

Comment: @khmarbaise in an earlier project we were forced to move our code from 1.6 to 1.7 ( code and project was inherited ) and one subtle bug introduced in production was the code was using reflection to get a list of methods and then firing calls to each of the method . The unfortunate part was that the code relied on reflection api to always return the methods in class in specific order ( which was the behaviour in 1.6 ) but after the issue cropped up in production ( and causing a lot of bad PR for me and our team ) , it was found that in jdk 1.7 reflection method order is not guaranteed ....

Comment: That sounds you seemed to have missing tests...which identified such things...in particular if you have made the experience...

Comment: no the tests were present for regression , thing is on every startup of the jvm the order of methods could / would change , so tests were performed and it passed , even after it failed in prod , we were only able to reproduce it after restarting the component multiple times and then once in a while we were able to reproduce

Answer (score 0):

There are two main aspects to understand:

1. The Maven toolchains plugin enables us to **separate** the JDK/JRE version being used for the projects **building Maven plugin execution runtime** from the JDK version being used to compile AND to run the surefire plugins running the JUnit tests.
2. The Maven compile plugins configuration `<target>` (user property `maven.compiler.target`) JAVA version defines the code and class JAVA version the compiler will create - BUT this does **NOT guarantee that your code will run 100%** on that **target versions actual JAVA runtime** (s. below under the risk headline).

Both topics have to be well understood in terms of risks and pre-requisites.

The most common required scenario is like this:

### Maven build execution requires JAVA version A
Target classes compiled require JAVA version B

In your questioned case you have to meet:

1. Use **JAVA 11** for **Maven build execution** to meet SonarQube plugin requirements
2. Use **JAVA 1.8** to **compile** and JUnit test your code

The correct configuration to meet this requirement is:

1. Define your **`JAVA_HOME`** being used to run the Maven build process to the **JDK 11** home
   => meets your **question #2**
2. Configure your **toolchains** plugin to make use of the **JDK 1.8** home
3. Configure the **maven-compiler-plugin**

```
...
  <configuration>
    <source>1.8</source>
    <target>1.8</target>
  </configuration>
...
```

=> **2.** and **3.** meet your **question #1**

### Potential risk if not configuring a separate toolchain

If you run the build with JDK 11 without having defined a separate JDK 8 by the toolchain, then your compiled classes will be compliant to JDK 8, **if** you configure the **maven-compiler-plugin** target to 1.8,

**__ BUT __**

- You compile your code **vs. the JDK 11 API (JDK's rt.jar)** - and by this your code would even get compiled if it is **using JAVA 11 API's** that are NOT available on JAVA 8 or did have been modified vs. JAVA 8.
  **=>** Your project goes risk to fail late on JAVA 8 runtime with unexpected and suspicious class not found or method missing exceptions.
- JUnit tests may endup different as if they would have been run within a JAVA 8 runtime.